# Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object' in LINQPad

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linqpad

So I am trying to convert a SQL stored procedure to Entity Framework which uses functions within subqueries to create temporary tables. There are several subqueries so I'm using LINQPad 4 and `.Dump()` to compare my Linq outputs to the original SQL outputs at each subquery (step by step within the procedure so to speak).

The first subquery uses a function which I know returns the right values (from `.Dump()` comparisons to the SQL function).

However, when I try to use that resulting `List<object>` in the subquery, it throws a

**NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.**

I have converted other procedures that use this function within our Visual Studio EntityFramework project with no issue, using the same kind of implementation as below. So why does LINQPad throw an exception and Visual Studio compiles and runs something like this just fine? I've tried using `AsEnumerable()` but it didn't fix the issue.

```
IDbDataParameter[] sqlParameters = new[] 
        {
            new SqlParameter("@userId", 1),
            new SqlParameter("@organizationId", 1),
            new SqlParameter("@displayId", 0)
        };

fnc_PRIV_AccessibleDisplays_List accessDisplaysList = new fnc_PRIV_AccessibleDisplays_List();
var accessibleDisplays = accessDisplaysList.Execute(sqlParameters) as List<object>;

var activeMenuItems = (from m in MENU_MenuItem
                   join d in PRIV_Displays on m.DisplayId equals d.Id
                   join ad in accessibleDisplays on d.Id equals Convert.ToInt32(ClassHelper.GetPropertyValue(ad, "Id"))
                   where (m.StatusId == 1)
                   select new
                   {
                     Id = m.DisplayId,
                     Name = m.Name,
                     DefaultName = m.Name,
                     Description = m.Description,
                     FolderId = m.FolderId,
                     OrderIndex = m.OrderIndex,
                     IconUrl = m.IconUrl,
                     ViewName = d.ClassName,
                     BackgroundColorId = m.BackgroundColorId,
                     IsModifiable = m.IsModifiable,
                     DisplayOpenMode = d.DisplayOpenMode,
                     iconCls = m.iconCls
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753202/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-system-object-in-entity-framework?rq=1)

Comment: I'm not using lambda expressions though. And it doesn't explain why a similar implementation works in VS but not in LINQPad